# run function resize with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function to set the width on page load.
and I try to update the width if a user tries to resize the window.
but function resizes keep show me the width that function on load generates.
how to make the function resize work?

```
 <div class="wrap">
  <p class="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum nulla minus mollitia est ab eveniet magni dolores perferendis, autem facilis.</p>
 <p class="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum nulla minus mollitia est ab eveniet magni dolores perferendis, autem facilis.</p>
</div>

var listEl = document.querySelector('.wrap');
var widthCont = listEl.offsetWidth;

/* set style on load page */
wdth();
function wdth(){
    listEl.style.width = widthCont+"px";
    console.log(widthCont);
}

/* run if resize window */
var onresize = function(e) {
   listEl.style.width = widthCont+"px";
   console.log(widthCont);
}
window.addEventListener("resize", onresize);
```

Comment: You're only reading `listEl.offsetWidth` once, at the start. `widthCont` is just a number, which won't magically update when `listEl.offsetWidth` updates.

Comment: because listEl.offsetWidth does not keep magically updating. It is just that value at the moment in time

Comment: so i need to call it inside function on resize again?

Comment: You need to read `listEl.offsetWidth` again to get an up-to-date value, yes.

Comment: Are you using css? If yes, see the corresponding tag if the size is not fixed. If you are trying to put it as none, maybe

Comment: yes and it makes no sense why you have two methods that do the same thing.